# Xcode 6: Have button stay in specific place over image view on all devices? Constraints?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm still getting the hang of auto layout with the constraints and all and I need help- I have an image view that scales to the screen of whatever device it's on, and I need to have a button be over a specific part of the image view on all devices. I've tried centering it, pinning it and tried copying exactly what is done here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk

And it isn't working. The button continues to be at a different spot when comparing an iPhone to an iPad and it changes sizes to be absurdly large and very small. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting both width and height constraints so the dimensions don't change. Then you could set a left and top constraints to fix the position.

Are you sure that the image view isn't being stretched on the different devices? That would cause a different piece of the UIView to appear under the button even if the button remained fixed in the same position across devices.

Comment: Yes, the image view is being stretched.I've tried setting the left and top constraints and it still isn't working

Comment: It sounds like the problem involves trying to tie the position of the button to the position of specific UIView content (which moves across devices) rather than relative to the UIView container boundaries. If this is the case then I think you would need to use the new size classes and introduce device specific constraints.

You can do this easily with the "w:Any h:Any" tool (sorry, forgot its real name but its something like Size Class Selector). Select the size classes for the iPhone orientations you need, set the button, then change the to the iPad size classes and repeat.

Comment: Ok. How exactly, as in step by step, does one introduce device specific constraints? So you click on the x:Any h:Any, and then..?

Comment: x:Any h:Any refers to Size Classes, and they aren't going to help you with the differences between an iPhone5, 6 and 6+.

Comment: Alright.. so using size classes, aren't you able to make different layouts for an iPhone and an iPad? How do you make separate size classes? @Abizern